# Toolchain for cross-compiling DLL to windows/arm64 from darwin/arm64

Tags: windows, go, cross-compiling, cgo

I'm currently using this command on my darwin/arm64 machine to cross-compile a DLL for windows/amd64

```
GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=1 CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc go build -o example.dll -buildmode=c-shared main.go
```

I would like to cross-compile for windows/arm64 and can't for the life of me figure out what the CC should be for that.

```
GOOS=windows GOARCH=arm64 CGO_ENABLED=1 CC=<what should I use?> go build -o example.dll -buildmode=c-shared main.go
```

I've done quite a bit of Googling and can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

Comment: [This query to a popular Internet search engine](https://www.google.com/search?q=mingw+arm64+target) yields [this](https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/1888). Also note that your question is [off-topic on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @kostix as I mentioned in the question, I've done quite a bit of Googling, and your link is not helpful as mingw does not have an arm64 target. LLVM does have an arm64 target, but I'm not sure which LLVM CC is compatible with Go. My question is not off-topic because it is "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development".

Comment: Worked for me with `llvm-mingw-20220906-msvcrt-ubuntu-18.04-x86_64.tar.xz` from [this release](https://github.com/mstorsjo/llvm-mingw/releases/tag/20220906) (now latest) with `GOOS=windows`, `GOARCH=arm64` and `CC=/path/to/unwrapped_archive/bin/aarch64-w64-mingw32-gcc`. The invocation of `file` on the resuting binary says `PE32+ executable (console) Aarch64, for MS Windows`. I'm on `linux/amd64`, but I hope `llvm-mingw-20220906-ucrt-macos-universal.tar.xz` should work for you.

Comment: I wonder why they do not have a `macos` build targetting `msvcrt`; dunno whether it's an issue for you or not.